# Why can't I make implicit cast operators from ValueTuple?

Tags: c#

I defined an implicit cast operator from `(float, LengthUnit)` to a struct called `Length` where `LengthUnit` is an enum I have defined.

This is my code:

```
    public static implicit operator Length(ValueTuple<float, LengthUnit> v)
    {
        return new Length(v.Item1, v.Item2);
    }
```

But whenever the operator is called, then I am greeted with a `MissingMethodException`:

> **System.MissingMethodException**: 'Method not found: '`` MyApp.Length MyApp.Length.op_Implicit(System.ValueTuple`2<Single,MyApp.LengthUnit>) ``'.'

If it is relevant, the `Length` structure is defined in a separate assembly from the one in which I am invoking the operator.

My question is why is this exception being thrown, and how do I make it stop?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, I cleaned my solution and rebuilt it.

Comment: No repro.  Microsoft screwed up pretty badly by releasing VS2017 before .NET 4.7 was ready.  Programmers had to limp along by using the Nuget package to get ValueTuple.  So one thing that can go wrong here (I can't check) is that the library uses the Nuget package as a reference but the main project uses the 4.7 version for the reference.

Comment: When I try to compile this code, I get the compiler error `CS0556 User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type` hth

Comment: @IanRay: did you put the `operator Length()` method into a type named `Length`?